# ios error [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

Tags: javascript, react-native, kotlin, c++14, openshift

npx pod-install
Scanning for pods...
1.12.1

> pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

```
at Object.dependencyConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/PRO/mobile/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js:102:37)

at /Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:47:61

at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

at getDependencyConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:44:51)

at Object.get react-native-splash-screen [as react-native-splash-screen] (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:99:18)

at /Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:16:51

at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

at filterConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:15:38)

at Object.func (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:27:32)

at Command.handleAction (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:23)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
'.

## from /Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/PRO/mobile/app/ios/Podfile:60

## -------------------------------------------

> use_native_modules!

## end

## -------------------------------------------

Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...

> pod install --repo-update

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

```
at Object.dependencyConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/PRO/mobile/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js:102:37)

at /Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:47:61

at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

at getDependencyConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:44:51)

at Object.get react-native-splash-screen [as react-native-splash-screen] (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:99:18)

at /Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:16:51

at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

at filterConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:15:38)

at Object.func (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:27:32)

at Command.handleAction (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:23)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
'.

## from /Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/PRO/mobile/app/ios/Podfile:60

## -------------------------------------------

> use_native_modules!

## end

## -------------------------------------------

Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Invalid `Podfile` file: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

```
at Object.dependencyConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/PRO/mobile/app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js:102:37)

at /Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:47:61

at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)

at getDependencyConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:44:51)

at Object.get react-native-splash-screen [as react-native-splash-screen] (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:99:18)

at /Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:16:51

at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

at filterConfig (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:15:38)

at Object.func (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/commands/config.js:27:32)

at Command.handleAction (/Users/dhanushraj/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:23)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
'.

## from /Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/PRO/mobile/app/ios/Podfile:60

## -------------------------------------------

> use_native_modules!

## end

## -------------------------------------------

```
                            Recreating a configuration
```

- configure: (autoconf)configure Invocation.
  Configuring a package
- ifnames: (autoconf)ifnames Invocation.
  Listing the conditionals in source code

GNU programming tools

- automake: (automake).         Making Makefile.in's

Utilities

- Bash: (bash).                     The GNU Bourne-Again SHell.

GNU Packages
-----Info: (dir)Top, 289 lines --24%------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Can you try to navigate to your project root and execute ```npx pod-install```

Comment: yes it fixed with yarn init and yarn install this will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is:

Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.

try this:-  `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.

try this:- yarn install